# Busqueda varios Id c# y sql, solo obtengo un dato

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

tengo una consulta como puedo hacer una busqueda de varios id de usuario a sql desde c#, ya que cree un forech que recorre una lista pero solo me trae el ultimo regiostro seleccionado, y el problema es que no me trae la informacion de los demas usuarios marcados, tal y coomo se muestra en la imagen

en c#

```
List<ListaEmpleado> eDetalleTabla = new List<ListaEmpleado>((IList<ListaEmpleado>)listaEmpleadoBindingSource.List);

  if (checkEdit1.Checked==false)
                {
                    var toDate = fechafin.Value;

                    RN_Marcaje obj = new RN_Marcaje();
                    DataTable datos = new DataTable();

                  
                    
                    foreach (ListaEmpleado Linea in eDetalleTabla)
                    {


                        if (Linea.Check==true)
                        {
                           
                            datos = obj.RN_Listar_MarcajePorTiempoUsuario(Convert.ToString(Linea.Id), Convert.ToDateTime(fechainicio.Value), new DateTime(toDate.Year, toDate.Month, toDate.Day, 23, 59, 59)); 
                           
                        }
                        


                    }
                    gridControl1.DataSource = datos;



                    //obj.GetReporte(Convert.ToDateTime(fechainicio.Value), new DateTime(toDate.Year, toDate.Month, toDate.Day, 23, 59, 59));
                }
```

y mi procedimiento en sql es

```
[![ALTER procedure \[dbo\].\[ReporteKardexPorPeriododeTiempoTodo\] 
@fechainicio datetime,
@fechaFin datetime,
@codigo char(50)


as
Select * from REPORTE_QUINCENAL_ASISTENCIA
where emp_pin in(@codigo) and Fecha between @fechainicio and @fechaFin 
order by Fecha asc, emp_firstname asc][1]][1]
```

Comment: Por el lado de SQL, esto: `in(@codigo)`  no hace lo que supones, el `IN` espera un conjuno de valores literales o un selección desde una tabla, y lo que estás haciendo es pasarle una cadena donde concatenas los id.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho igual el error no esta ahi.. el error es que hace este query N veces, en lugar de llamarlo luego de concatenar los valores que quiere buscar....

Comment: entiendo, tendria que concatenarlos desde c#, como puedo hacer eso si es en un foreach.

Comment: justamente porque es un foreach es mucho mas simple.. que parte no te sale????

Comment: Lo que no se es como concatenar los dalos de Linea.id del foreach :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en que `dato` lo vuelves a llamar y pisar en cada iteración.

Como tu SP pide una lista de string separados por coma puedes usar `string.join(separador, lista)` para convertir ese array en un string

```
if (checkEdit1.Checked==false)
{
    var toDate = fechafin.Value;

    RN_Marcaje obj = new RN_Marcaje();
    DataTable datos = new DataTable();

    var ids = eDetalleTabla.Where(a=>a.Check==true).Select(a=>a.Id);
    var idsString = string.Join(",",ids );
                           
    datos = obj.RN_Listar_MarcajePorTiempoUsuario(idsString, Convert.ToDateTime(fechainicio.Value), new DateTime(toDate.Year, toDate.Month, toDate.Day, 23, 59, 59));
```

Comment: Hola Yussef, fijate que desde c# si funciona bien la comprobacion tal y como la hiciste pero no obtengo los datos auque si existan.

Comment: El SP no pide una lista de datos separados por comas. El SP va a devolver los datos de un solo código. Si se le envía una cadena con datos de varios códigos separados por comas y no existe un código exactamente así, diría que no va a devolver nada.